# Working on including Scores in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add scores in my game (i'm learning how to make games in Android), Now I have my button which checks if the answer is correct and another button which you click next to continue.

I want players to be able to play the game such that once the answer is correct they get `1` score and if they get it wrong the score stays `0` ;My Button which checks if the answer is correct is where i want to set the scores (unless if i am doing it the wrong way) i dont want to display them on the same layout as the game but instead i have installed a timer and at finish i want the result to pop out(this i have an idea of how to do it).

Now I have tried this and my game is not getting scores and once i ran the code it is okay but gives me the following

d

```
by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
            at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
            at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:525)
            at com.systematixnote.basicmathoperation.MathQuestion.getScore(MathQuestion.java:390)
            at com.systematixnote.basicmathoperation.MathQuestion.setHighScore(MathQuestion.java:274)
            at com.systematixnote.basicmathoperation.MathQuestion.onDestroy(MathQuestion.java:319)
            at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:6169)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3696)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3727)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1357)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

.. any help offered will be appreciated at this level.

I bluntly have no idea on this one but any assistance will be appreciated

Sample Code:
My Button

```
   public void onClickCheck(View view){
        int answer;
    try{
        String ans = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.answerField)).getText().toString();


        answer = Integer.valueOf(ans);

        if(answer == q.getAnswer()){

            correct = true;
            counter++;



        }else if(correct ==true){
            getScore();

        }else if(answer != q.getAnswer()){
            setHighScore();


            counter = 0;
        }
```

Get Score;

```
public int getScore() {
      int answer;
      String ans = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.answerField)).getText().toString();


      answer = Integer.valueOf(ans);
        return Integer.parseInt(ans.substring(answer));
    }


protected void onDestroy(){
        setHighScore();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: you need to be more precise on what is **not working**

Comment: Okay i have updated that, thanks

Comment: your stack trace is not complete, we can't see what is the exception

Comment: There couple of things I notise. 1 you instantiated your editText twice; in getScore()  and onClickCheck. Also you call getScore() in onClickCheck but did not pass the returned value to any Variables. So in onClickCheck do this answer = getScore();

Comment: It is a good practice to write down the flow of instructions or controls in.your program before coding which mostly helps locate problem/bugs in.your prog. I.will advise you to write down how the program is likely to be execute and compare that with your code. Use "Pseudo code"

Comment: Actually i was following an online tutorial and tried to do this. @Want2bExpert so what am i doing wrong? I have changed as you said

Comment: @DerekFung I now have the exception i have updated it on the question, I am learning Android on my own and will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: What class is q? Because you using q.getAnswer()?

Comment: q is where i define my questions methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the problem with your `getScore` method, change it like this

```
public int getScore() {
  int answer;
  String ans = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.answerField)).getText().toString();

    try {

      return Integer.valueOf(ans);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //value in answerField is not Integer do whatever you need
      //return -1, just to make it complete, you should change it
      return -1;
    }
```

you still need to do more because `Integer.valueOf(ans)` will throw exception if the text in the field is not Integer

**Edit:**

FYI on why your original code not working,

assume when `ans` has value `"123"`, answer would have value `123`, but you continue to perform `Integer.parseInt(ans.substring(answer));`, and `ans.substring(answer)` is equivalent to `"123".substring(123)` and it will return the substring starting from position 123, but the length of the string is 3, therefore it returns an empty String

and finally `Integer.parseInt("")` would throw error because the input is not an Integer

Comment: The method is supposed to retrieve the scores , I have changed it but still gave me the exception. But i can see what your're talking about. Let try to work on it

Comment: I believe the exception change, add it as an edit in your post, if it does not, it simply means, your answerField is empty, you should add check and catch exception for that

Comment: updated the example to show you how to catch exception

Comment: Thats true let me play around with this appreciated.